# Allowing only one connection among multiple openvpn servers

Tags: linux, openvpn

Just wondering it's possible to allow only one connection among multiple openvpn servers?

For example, if I have 3 openvpn servers like below, I want the client to connect only one of the servers among 3.

It looks 3 openvpn servers share some information. Is it possible?

server1.conf

```
server 172.16.0.0 255.255.255.0
dev tun
proto tcp
port PORT
keepalive 10 120
push "route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0"

ca cacert.pem
cert server1.crt
key server1.key
dh dh1024.pem
```

server2.conf

```
server 10.0.110.0 255.255.255.0
dev tun
proto tcp
port PORT
keepalive 10 120
push "route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0"

ca cacert.pem
cert server2.crt
key server2.key
dh dh1024.pem
```

server3.conf

```
server 10.0.50.0 255.255.255.0
dev tun
proto tcp
port PORT
keepalive 10 120
push "route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0"

ca cacert.pem
cert server3.crt
key server3.key
dh dh1024.pem
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the radius authentication over your current certificate based authentication.

Checkout https://openvpn.net/access-server-manual/authentication-radius/

Radius allows you to control the simultaneous sessions for each user and set them to a fixed number.

Checkout https://wiki.freeradius.org/config/Users#special-attributes-used-in-the-users-file